# KVM: how to add vm to specific bridge

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am attempting to add a vm to a vlan which I've created via a bridge. 
I have a server with 4 NIC's. 2 (eno1 and eno2) are 1Gig management NIC's and the other 2 (enp1s0f0 and enp1s0f1) are 10Gig forwarding NIC's.
Here is my network config via .yaml in netplan:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1: {}
        eno2: {}
        enp1s0f0: {}
        enp1s0f1: {}

    bonds:
        bond_10G:
            interfaces:
            - enp1s0f0
            - enp1s0f1
            parameters:
                mode: balance-rr
        bond_mgmt:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.21.228/24
            gateway4: 192.168.21.1
            interfaces:
            - eno1
            - eno2
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.91.5
                - 192.168.91.6
                search:
                - blah.net
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
    vlans:
        vlan66:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            accept-ra: no
            id: 66
            link: bond_10G
        vlan69:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            accept-ra: no
            id: 69
            link: bond_10G
        vlan2232:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            accept-ra: no
            id: 2232
            link: bond_10G

    bridges:
        br66:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            interfaces: [ vlan66 ]
        br69:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            interfaces: [ vlan69 ]
        br2232:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            interfaces: [ vlan2232 ]
```

I can see them all when I do a `brctl show`:

```
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br2232          8000.9e3e2f786260       no              vlan2232
br66            8000.16545d040c3a       no              vlan66
br69            8000.92c5912a358b       no              vlan69
virbr0          8000.525400e3bdfa       yes             virbr0-nic
```

When I log into this QEMU/KVM via virt-manager, I only get the virbr0 option and the other bridges are not listed as options to add them. Is there a way to do this via `virsh` or am I simply doing it wrong in virt-manager?

I also tried to add it via `virt-install` but it didn't drop into the correct vlan:

```
sudo virt-install \
--name deb9-vm \
--ram 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/deb9-vm.qcow2,size=20 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant debian9 \
--network bridge=br66 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--location 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/installer-amd64/' \
--extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

I guess my question is how do I get the other bridges to show up as options for a vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libvirt (and thereby virt-manager, virt-install, ...) do not probe/know the actual bridges on the system. You have already defined your vlans and bridges via netplan, which is great and the correct step #1.

By default there only is the `default` network which is a NAT based local bridge, you need to define a network. In that you control what bridges, forwarding modes and so on are used - and if libvirt is supposed to spawn e.g. dhcp on it (like it would do on the local default bridge).

There is the great resource of [netplan examples](https://netplan.io/examples#configuring-network-bridges) which are extended still as yet undocumented cases are found. But your case is rather common and in there, it also has a minimal snippet of that libvirt network xml like:

```
<network>
  <name>vlan66</name>
  <bridge name='br66'/>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
</network>
```

Using the above and adapting it to your needs you can then `virsh net-define <xmlfilename>` which will make libvirt know about the network. You then can see them in `virsh net-list` but in virt-manager and the other tools.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.